# subprocess как ответить на вопрос после вызова команды

Tags: python, subprocess

Использую библиотеку subprocess. (os не подходит, т.к. глюки с кодировками)

Вызвал команду, затем просят дать ответ: Y, N или C.

Как ответить на этот вопрос? (Вверху обычная консоль, чтобы было понятнее. просто с кодировкой какая-то фигня.)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если в субпроцессе ровно один ввод, то следующее должно сработать:

```
import subprocess

answer = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
answer.communicate(input=input().encode())
```